# List.js is not working for tables

Tags: javascript, html, search, listjs

I'm trying to use list.js to implement a "live" searching on a table. I have tested successfully on lists (doing something like the example in http://listjs.com/examples/existing-list). However, I cannot replicate this behavior for tables.

I have done this small code to replicate the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Test try</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="list.min.js"></script>

</head><body>

<div id="payload">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search">
<table style="border: 1px solid black">
    <thead>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="list" >
        <tr>
            <td class="a">Lorem </td>
            <td class="b">ipsum </td>
            <td class="c">dolor </td>
            <td class="d">sit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="a">amet</td>
            <td class="b">consectetur </td>
            <td class="c">adipiscing  </td>
            <td class="d"> elit </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
    var options = {ValueNames: ['a','b','c','d']};
    var searchable = new List('payload', options);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For some reason I could not determine, this is not working, in FF any input on the search field clears the table body, and deleting it doesn't restore the table neither. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the variable name `ValueNames` that should be `valueNames`. A working example of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pTEJ3/

Comment: Hallo @pna, is there anyway to have multiple searchfields for the same table to give each column his own searchfield ?